# How to rename an private file of my application?

Tags: android

I want to rename an context private file created with openFileOutput() but I don't know how...

I tried that:

```
File file = getFileStreamPath(optionsMenuView.getPlaylistName()); // this file already exists

                try {
                    FileOutputStream outStream = openFileOutput(newPlaylistName, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE); // i create a new file with the new name
                    outStream.close();
                }
                catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "file not found!");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } 
                catch (IOException e) {

                    Log.e(TAG, "IO exception");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }                           

                Log.e(TAG, "rename status: " + file.renameTo(getFileStreamPath(newPlaylistName))); //it return true
```

This code throw FileNotFoundException but the documentation said "Open a private file associated with this Context's application package for writing. **Creates the file if it doesn't already exist**." so the new file should be created on disk.
 The problem: When I try to read from the new renamed file I got FileNotFoundException!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use the `File` class's `renameTo()` method?

Comment: renameTo() from File is not working for internal storage files

Answer (score 2):

Here's a method to rename a file stored in your app's private store:

```
// Renames a file stored in the application's private store.
public static void RenameAppFile(Context context, String originalFileName, String newFileName) {
    File originalFile = context.getFileStreamPath(originalFileName);
    File newFile = new File(originalFile.getParent(), newFileName);
    if (newFile.exists()) {
        // Or you could throw here.
        context.deleteFile(newFileName);        
    }
    originalFile.renameTo(newFile);
}
```